# How to stop scrolling of tableview while its cell contain signature pad is used in Swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift4

If cell of tableview contains signature pad and user is signing then tableview move upward making it difficult for user to sign? 
Is there any solution to stop scrolling  when user is signing?

I'm using `EPSignature` for signature view .

Comment: You are showing that in tableview cell ? you can implement touch methods and on touch down on that signature view you can disable user interaction and enable when touch released

Comment: use scrollEnabled property with @Prashant  suggestion.